# Verificar datos tipo double de un fichero C#

Tags: c#, .net

Extrayendo información de un fichero se ha de calcular la media de las notas de los alumnos cada línea del fichero contendrá lo siguiente :

Nombre Apellido  ;nota1;nota2;nota3;nota4;nota5;nota6;nota7;nota8

```
using System;
using Funciones;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ENT0501
{
    class Program
{
    //DECLARAR RUTA ARCHIVOS SALIDA Y ENTRADA
    public static String rutaEntrada = "Datos_notas.csv";
    public static String rutaSalida = "Salida.txt";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Ficheros.tratarFichero();
        Console.Write("\n\n\tPULSAR CUALQUIER TELCA PARA FINALIZAR...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}


using System;
using System.IO;
using ENT0501;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Funciones
{
   class Ficheros
   {
       public static void tratarFichero()
       {
             //DECLARAR VARIABLES 
            StreamReader ficheroLectura = null;
            String[] lineaDesfragmentada = new string[0];
            String linea = "";
            String final = "";
            int contador = 1;
        try
        {
            //ABRIR FICHERO DE ENTRADA
            ficheroLectura = new StreamReader(Program.rutaEntrada);
            File.Delete(Program.rutaSalida);


            //REPETIR HASTA QUE String linea RETORNE VALOR NULL
            while ((linea = ficheroLectura.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //SALTAR LAS LÍNEAS PARES E INCREMENTAR PARA SALTAR A LA SIGUIENTE
                if (contador % 2 == 0)
                    contador++;
                //TRATAR LAS LÍNEAS IMPARES E INCREMENTAR PARA SALTAR A LA SIGUIENTE
                else
                {
                    contador++;

                    //AUMENTAR LA LONGITUDAD DEL ARRAY
                    Array.Resize(ref lineaDesfragmentada, lineaDesfragmentada.Length + 1);
                    //ELIMINAR ';' DEL FICHERO Y DIVIDIRLO EN PARTES
                    lineaDesfragmentada = linea.Split(';');

                    //IMPRIMIR NOMBRE Y DATOS ALMACENADOS EN LAS VARIABLES NÚMERICAS
                    final = final + lineaDesfragmentada[0] + ';' + calcular(lineaDesfragmentada) + "\n";
                }
            }
            //CERRAR FICHERO DE ENTRADA
            ficheroLectura.Close();
            imprimir(final);
        }
        //SI HA SURGIDO UN ERROR, LANZAR MENSAJE Y SALIR
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message.ToUpper());
        }
    }
    public static void imprimir(String contenido)
    {
        StreamWriter ficheroEscritura = null;
        try
        {
            ficheroEscritura = File.CreateText(Program.rutaSalida);
            ficheroEscritura.Write(contenido);
            ficheroEscritura.Close();             
        }
        //SI HA SURGIDO UN ERROR, LANZAR MENSAJE Y SALIR
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.Write(Ex.Message.ToUpper());
        }
    }
    public static Double calcular(String[] linea)
    {
        double entregas = 0;
        double intervenciones = 0;
        double pruebas = 0;

        //VERIFICAR DATOS, SUMAR NOTAS, HALLAR MEDIAS Y PONDERACIONES
        entregas = ((Double.Parse(linea[1]) + Double.Parse(linea[2]) + Double.Parse(linea[3])) / 3) * 0.3;
        intervenciones = ((Double.Parse(linea[4]) + Double.Parse(linea[5]) + Double.Parse(linea[6])) / 3) * 0.2;
        pruebas = ((Double.Parse(linea[7]) + Double.Parse(linea[8])) / 2) * 0.5;

        return Math.Truncate(entregas + intervenciones + pruebas);
    }
}
 }
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo realizar un tryparse de las notas para poder controlar los errores en el método calcular?

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta. No sabes usar double.tryparse? leiste la documentacion?

Comment: He estado buscando la solución durante de horas pero no sé cómo hacer la verificación correctamente, he recurrido a postear ya que tengo un examen mañana y seguramente eso entre

Comment: Pero lo que no entedes es como funciona tryparse?

Answer (score 0):

El `TryParse()` se puede usar de varias formas

- validando si el valor pudo ser convertido al tipo de datos y avisando del problema
- definiendo un valor por defecto y sino conviertes continuas igualmente con este valor predefinido.

Para validarlo usas que `bool` que retorna el `tryparse`

```
double val1 = 0;
if(Double.TryParse(linea[1], out val1)){
   MessageBox.Show("Valor Incorrecto {0}", linea[1]);
   return;
}
```

Para continuar con el valor por defecto simplemente lo intentas y sigues

```
double val1 = 0;
Double.TryParse(linea[1], out val1);
```

Si puede convertir dejara el valor cero en la variable, pero no fallara

Esto mismo puede aplicar al resto de las posiciones numericas que tengas que convertir

[TryParse(String, Double)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__)

Hay otra alternativa tambien cuando quieres convertir pero asignando a un objeto

```
double val1 = 0;
if(Double.TryParse(linea[1], out val1)){
   obj.Prop1 = val1;
}
```

no lo informas pero si puede convertir asignas el valor al objeto que despues continuas utilizando